# Unwanted threads in javafx app

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I created a small app from this oracle tutorial [HelloWorld app](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm)

But when I launch it I get 2 unwanted threads:

[image: unwanted threads]

Who invokes these daemon threads? I don't have any specific code, just copy pasted from example.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple threads are spawned during the creation of a JavaFX application. These are useful for completing the [JavaFX Application Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm).

Most of these are generated for completing the `Graphics System` of JavaFX Architecture. You may want to go through the [Thread section of Glass Windowing Toolkit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438) which states :

> The system runs two or more of the following threads at any given
>   time.
>
> 1. JavaFX application thread
> 2. Prism render thread
> 3. Media thread